# ('#').dialog is not a function error after using jQuery's .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, jquery-load

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Confirmar',
        'resizable'=>'false',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'modal'=>true,      
        'buttons'=>array('Eliminar'=>'js:function(){deleteMessage();$(this).dialog("close");}',
                         'Cancelar'=>'js:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}',),
    ),
));?>
<div style="display:none">Do you confirm you want to delete the item?</div> 
<?php 
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>

<input type="button" onclick="js:openDlg()" value="Open the dialog">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openDlg(){
        $("#mydialog").dialog("open"); 
    }
</script>
```

This works PERFECTLY, until i needed to call jQuery's .load() function. For testing purposes, i have a button which calls the .load() method (although supposedly it should be called when the doc is ready). If i hit the open dialog button before clicking this trial button, the dialog opens correctly. Else, it fails with the following error:

$("#mydialog").dialog is not a function
$("#mydialog").dialog("open");

Trial button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="js:load_wall()" value="Load Messages">
function load_wall(){
        var liga = $("#liga_id").val();
        $('#div_wall_messages').load('displayMessages',{liga_id: liga}, function(){

        });
```

Please, any help is more than welcome. This error is driving me crazy. thank you!!

Comment: What is `$this`? I don't know any object with that method.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin CJuiDialog is a widget provided by the framework i am using, Yii. It encapsulates the JUI Dialog plugin.

Comment: Abstract your PHP out of this question. It's utterly irrelevant. Talk to us about your preprocessed HTML/JS output instead.

Comment: @Rikudo: This *is* a jQuery question; the PHP should be removed from the question, rather than the Javascript removed from the tags.

Comment: Can you show us the html? Specifically, where is the #div_wall_messages in relation to #mydialog?  Is #mydialog inside #div_wall_messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's `displayMessages`? Is it a page with scripts in it? Is it a page that includes another copy of jQuery? If you include a second copy of jQuery you will be overwriting your existing copy—possibly you are overwriting a jQuery that has the Dialog plugin loaded into it with a new one that doesn't.

If you want to load into a div and what you've got in the file being loaded is a full page of HTML (including `<head>`, `<script>`s et al), then you should only load the fragment of content (by `id`) that you want into your target. In all cases avoid `load()`ing HTML content that contains `<script>`; the results are, depending on circumstance, either nothing, or nothing sensible.

Also `js:` in all your code above does nothing and should be omitted.

Comment: Thank you @bobince! I would have never solved this on my own. Yes, displayMessages is an action which renders another page that had scripts in it. So that is exactly what was going on, i was replacing the already loaded javascript

Answer (score 1):

If the load is the problem, it's likely that you've loaded (and overwritten) the currently loaded libraries, which might include jQuery with your dialog plugin. Make sure you load a clean page, (Whenever I AJAX, I generally only generate a single `<div>` or a `<ul>`, whatever I need, and not the entire webpage.

If that fails, make sure the proper javascript files are included, that include jQuery and seemingly also jQuery UI.

Check in your browser's network/resources tracking what's up with those script files, and see if there are any other error messages (maybe a 404 not found?) on the javascript files.

Comment: im sorry for rejecting the tags suggestion. But looking more into it i really don't see why it shouldn't be tagged as a jquery/javascript issue. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

As already explained above, you probably override the libraries.

One way of dealing with it is to ensure that the correct files are loaded.

Another way is to insert an iframe between the dialog and the content in the dialog. Iframes are treated by the browser as a separate page with its own scripts. So the scripts of the content "on top of" the iframe, will be separate from the scripts of the dialog "under" the iframe.

Since you are using Yii, check this [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/263/cgridview-update-create-records-in-a-cjuidialog).